# How to fix only last line of array being checked for username and password when read from a file

Tags: java, arrays, file

I am reading usernames from a csv file in the format

```
admin1, apple,  admin
staff1, orange, staff
```

with staff1 being on a new line and no matter how many lines I have, only the last line will be checked when login is occurring.

```
        AtomicBoolean found = new AtomicBoolean(false);

   btnLogin.setOnAction(e -> {
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {


            String s = in.nextLine().replaceAll("\\s+", "");





                if (name.equals(sArray[0]) && password.equals(sArray[1])) {
                    lMessage.setText("correct");
                    openMainForm();


                } else if (name.equals("") || password.equals("")) {
                    lMessage.setText("Please enter a username and password");


                } else {
                    lMessage.setText("Please enter valid credentials");



                }




            }


        });
```

I expect that if the username and password combination is found in the file they will be able to login and not just if the username and password is the last in the time

Comment: You overwrite the action that will be taken when the button is pressed for each of the lines, only the last action you define will be executed when the button is pressed.

Comment: Also, I would put the while loop inside the `setOnAction` handler.

Comment: The easiest way would be to iterate over the file's content inside the function that is passed to `setOnAction` as suggested by Kartik Soneji : call `setOnAction` a single time (outside of a loop), but have it do what it does once per line instead of a single time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are setting the action in a loop. That is, one action object being created for every pair and then being assigned. So, after last iteration, the action will be set to the latest object, which is obviously checking for last pair of username-password.

the loop translates to something like,

> setOnAction(actionobject1 that checks for admin1, apple,  admin)
>
> setOnAction(actionobject2 that checks for staff1, orange, staff)

That effectively keeps last created object and check only for last pair

You might want to modify your logic so that there is only one action object. And then check for valid username-password pair.

Something like this:

```
btnLogin.setOnAction(e -> {

     while (in.hasNextLine() ) {
        // check condition here
        // don't forget to break when successful

      }
        in.close();
    });
```

Also, make sure you break the loop once successful pair is found. Otherwise the same thing will happen.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191691/discussion-on-answer-by-ankit-how-to-fix-only-last-line-of-array-being-checked-f).